# f is in L1 if and only if a series condition holds

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Assume that $f \in L^{+}$, that $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and that $\mu(E) < \infty$.  Prove that $L^{1}(E)$ iff
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k \mu(E_{k})
\end{align}
where $E_{k} = \{ x \in E: \; k \leq f(x) < k+1 \}$

So far I have tried the following, and I have bad emotions about this being wrong.

Assuming that $f \in L^{1}(E)$, since $E = \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} E_{k}$, which are disjoint sets
\begin{align}
\infty &> \int_{E} f d\mu \\
\text{(simple functions } \phi \leq f) \qquad  &\geq \sum_{k = 0}^{N} k \mu(E_{k}) + 0*\mu(E \backslash\bigcup_{k = 0}^{N}E_{k})
\end{align}
for all $N$.  So, we can take $N \rightarrow \infty$ and get that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k\mu(E_{k}) < \infty.
\end{align}
So it converges by MON.

For the second direction, I want to say that if
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k \mu(E_{k}) = K < \infty
\end{align}
Then it must be the case that
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k \mu(E_{k}) \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow \mu(E_{k}) = 0
\end{align}
Now, I want to use this fact to say that since $\mu(E) < \infty$, and $f \subset L^{+}$, and that though $f$ does not have a uniform bound, it is almost everywhere finite, that $f \in L^{1}(E)$.  However, I don't know what machinery is required to make that leap (if it can be made).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to note that $$\int_E  fd\mu=\sum \int_{E_k} f d\mu$$

Now the estimate to the left reads $$\sum k\mu(E_k)\leqslant \int_E fd\mu$$

The estimate to the right gives $$\int_E fd\mu \leqslant \sum(k+1)\mu(E_k)= \sum k\mu(E_k)+\mu(E)$$

Since $\mu(E) $ is finite, this means the integral is finite if and only if the sum is finite, as desired.

Comment: Thanks Pedro.  I think one of my broader questions from my approach above was as follows:  If $f$ is a.e. finite and measurable, is it in $L^{1}$?

Comment: @DRich No. Consider any nonzero constant function in a space of infinite measure, like $\Bbb R$. This is finite everywhere and measurable, but obviously not integrable.

Comment: If $\mu(E) < \infty$?

Comment: @DRich Still, no. Consider $X=(0,1)$ and $f(t) = t^{-1}$. This is finite everywhere and not integrable.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Just trying to get my counterexamples in order